# Object Reference Not Set... Arm Chain Generator Not Working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

So this one is a bit convoluted.

It started off with trying to learn kinematics for procedural animation. Then I went on a tangent about generating thicker lines. Now I'm trying to produce a program that generates a chain of inter-connected lines made out of DrawSpheres with variable length/angle/resolution.

I had the original single line functioning perfectly. But I can not get the program to generate more. Each line is generated at the end target of the previous line, but there seems to be no starting object to reference. What do I change?

The individual line code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System;

public class Arm
{
    public GameObject joint;

    [Range(0, 10), HideInInspector]
    public float length;

    [Range(-360, 360), HideInInspector]
    public float angle;

    [HideInInspector]
    public Transform origin;

    [Range(0, 2560), HideInInspector]
    public int density;

    [Range(0, 256), HideInInspector]
    public float thickness;

    public Vector3 Target()
    {
        Vector3 target = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        target.x = origin.position.x + Mathf.Cos(this.angle) * this.length;
        target.y = origin.position.y + Mathf.Sin(this.angle) * this.length;

        return target;
    }

    public Arm(float length, float angle, Vector3 origin, int resolution, float thickness, Vector3 target)
    {
        this.length = length;
        this.angle = angle;
        this.origin.position = origin;
        this.density = resolution;
        this.thickness = thickness;

    }

    public void GenerateLine()
    {
        Vector3[] lineSegments = new Vector3[density];
        float segmentLength = length / lineSegments.Length;

        lineSegments[0] = (origin.position);

        for(int i = 1; i < lineSegments.Length; i++)
        {
            lineSegments[i].x = lineSegments[i - 1].x + Mathf.Cos(this.angle/57.3f) * segmentLength;
            lineSegments[i].y = lineSegments[i - 1].y + Mathf.Sin(this.angle/57.3f) * segmentLength;

            Gizmos.color = Color.black;
            Gizmos.DrawSphere(lineSegments[i], thickness / 1000);
        }

    }
}
```

The Chain manager code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ArmChain : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0, 5)]
    public int chainLength;

    [Range(0, 10)]
    public float length;

    [Range(-360, 360)]
    public float angle;

    public Transform origin;

    [Range(0, 2560)]
    public int resolution;

    [Range(0, 256)]
    public float thickness;

    public Vector3 Target()
    {
        Vector3 target = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        target.x = this.transform.position.x + Mathf.Cos(this.angle) * this.length;
        target.y = this.transform.position.y + Mathf.Sin(this.angle) * this.length;

        return target;
    }

    public Transform jointOrigin;

    [SerializeField, HideInInspector]
    public Arm[] arms;

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Initialize();
        GenerateChain();
    }


    void Initialize()
    {
        Arm[] arms = new Arm[chainLength];

        for (int i = 1; i < chainLength; i++)
        {
            arms[i] = new Arm(arms[i - 1].length, arms[i].angle, arms[i - 1].Target(), arms[i - 1].density, arms[i - 1].thickness, arms[i].Target());
        }
    }

    public void GenerateChain()
    {
        foreach (Arm arm in arms)
        {
            arm.GenerateLine();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from derHugo, and a C# youtube tutorial series by Caleb Curry I have found the solution. The issue came from lack of understanding of classes and the difference between static and non-static methods.

Here's the code, it's a fun little bit of code that makes a simple forward kinematic arm.

The solution was really simple. I changed both the Target method and GenerateLine methods to be static. Then I changed initialize so that the object was actually created for each loop.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Arm
{
    public float length { get; set; }

    public float angle { get; set; }

    public Vector3 origin { get; set; }

    public int resolution { get; set; }

    public float thickness { get; set; }

    public Vector3 target { get; set; }

    static public Vector3 Target(Vector3 origin, float angle, float length)
    {
        Vector3 target;

        target.x = origin.x + Mathf.Cos(angle) * length;
        target.y = origin.y + Mathf.Sin(angle) * length;
        target.z = 0;

        return target;
    }

    static public void GenerateLine(int resolution, float length, Vector3 origin, float angle, float thickness)
    {
        Vector3[] lineSegments = new Vector3[resolution];
        float segmentLength = length / lineSegments.Length;

        lineSegments[0] = origin;

        for(int i = 1; i < lineSegments.Length; i++)
        {
            lineSegments[i].x = lineSegments[i - 1].x + Mathf.Cos(angle) * segmentLength;
            lineSegments[i].y = lineSegments[i - 1].y + Mathf.Sin(angle) * segmentLength;

            Gizmos.color = Color.black;
            Gizmos.DrawSphere(lineSegments[i], thickness);
        }

    }
}
```

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ArmChain : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0, 100)]
    public int chainLength;

    [Range(0, 10)]
    public float length;

    [Range(-.02f * 3.141592f, .02f * 3.141592f)]
    public float angle;

    [Range(0, 2560)]
    public int resolution;

    public Transform jointOrigin;

    [Range(0, 2560)]
    public float thickness;

    [SerializeField, HideInInspector]
    public Arm[] arms;

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Initialize();
        GenerateChain();
    }


    void Initialize()
    {
        arms = new Arm[chainLength];

        arms[0] = new Arm();

        arms[0].length = length;
        arms[0].angle = angle;
        arms[0].origin = jointOrigin.position;
        arms[0].resolution = resolution;
        arms[0].thickness = thickness;
        arms[0].target = Arm.Target(jointOrigin.position, angle, length);

        for (int i = 1; i < chainLength; i++)
        {
            arms[i] = new Arm();
            arms[i].length = length;
            arms[i].angle = arms[i - 1].angle + angle;
            arms[i].origin = arms[i - 1].target;
            arms[i].resolution = resolution;
            arms[i].thickness = thickness;
            arms[i].target = Arm.Target(arms[i].origin, arms[i].angle, length);
        }
    }

    public void GenerateChain()
    {
       for(int i = 0; i < chainLength; i++)
        {
            Arm.GenerateLine(arms[i].resolution, arms[i].length, arms[i].origin, arms[i].angle, arms[i].thickness);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you do

```
arms[i] = new Arm(arms[i - 1].length, arms[i].angle, arms[i - 1].Target(), arms[i - 1].density, arms[i - 1].thickness, arms[i].Target());
```

- well what is `arms[0]` ..? You never create it so the very first `arms[i - 1]` already returns `null`.
- and further note the last access to `arms[i].Target()`

  => if `arms[i]` has never been set yet (because you are just going to do this) then there won't be anything at `arms[i]`.

---

Besides that you do

```
Arm[] arms = new Arm[chainLength];
```

which hides the class field `arms`

=> when you call `GenerateChain` the field `arms` was never initialized.

You rather would want

```
void Initialize()
{
    arms = new Arm[chainLength];

    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the first portion a bit more? I made the adjustment to the initialize, no change though.

Comment: Well for the first there isn't really a solution .. it is quite unclear how this is supposed to work .. you are trying to access an object before it was created

Comment: I'm still learning, so I don't have a good foundation of knowledge yet. I had assumed "arms = new Arm[chainLength];" creates an array of objects whereby the for loop fills the individual objects with their respective values, ready to be generated.  What does declaring arms[] create and how do I create the actual object. If that is too broad of a question, where can I go to improve my foundation of knowledge.

Comment: `new Arm[5]` e.g. creates a new array ready to hold `5` instances of `Arm` .. but all 5 items will still be `null` until you assign something to them. The issue is that you are trying to access the first arm (`arms[0]`) but you never have created and assigned that `Arm`. And later while you are still in the process of creating and assigning `arms[i]` you are already trying to access and use a value of `arms[i]` which is still `null` as well since it isn't assigned yet.